# Retrieve a filtered ForeignKey with Django

Tags: python, django, tags, django-queryset, prefetch

I have three main models, Picture, Place and PlaceRating:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    file = ImageField(max_length=500, upload_to="images")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name="userpictures")
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, null=True, related_name='pictures')

class PlaceRating(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, null=True, related_name="placeratings")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name="userratings")   
    rating = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)     

class Place(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
```

I would like to display the place's rating given by the user, together with the place's image, but I cannot manage to do that as I would need to filter the ForeignKey and Django does not seem to allow that.

Example of what I would like to do:

View:

```
pictures = Picture.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Template:

```
{% for picture in pictures %}
    <img src="{{ picture.file.url }}" class="bigpicture">
    {{ picture.place.placeratings.0.rating|user:picture.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

For information, I managed to do it with templatetags, but this generates a lot of different queries to the database which I can't prefetch..:

```
{% for picture in pictures %}
    <img src="{{ picture.file.url }}">
    {% getplaceratingrelatedtopic picture.place.id picture.user.id %}
{% endfor %}
```

And:

```
@register.simple_tag
def getplaceratingrelatedtopic(placeid, userid):
    print(placeid)
    theplace = Place.objects.get(id=placeid)
    user = User.objects.get(id=userid)
    placerating = PlaceRating.objects.filter(author=user, place=place).last()
    if rating:
        return placerating.rating
    else:
        return ""
```

I work with Python 2.7/Django 1.9.

Any clue ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should move the logic to the model and use it in the template.

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    file = ImageField(max_length=500, upload_to="images")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name="userpictures")
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, null=True, related_name='pictures')


class PlaceRating(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, null=True, related_name="placeratings")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name="userratings")   
    rating = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)     


class Place(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def rating(self):
        return self.placeratings.get().rating

{% for picture in picture_list %}
    <img src="{{ picture.file.url }}" class="bigpicture">
    {{ picture.place.rating }}: {{ picture.user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But this does not filter the rating to only ratings posted by the user. I would need something like: 
    @property
    def rating(self):
        return self.placeratings.filter(user=request.user)[0].rating
        .. which is not accepted by Django.